# randomizing data by category in R

Tags: r

So I am a bit new with R, so forgive me if this is a silly question. I have a data set of behaviors that looks something like this:

```
time      behavior 
10:04:36  FEED     
10:04:37  FEED      
10:04:38  REST 
10:04:39  REST
10:04:40  RUN
```

etc..

I have added a column that numbers each new behavior as a unique number, something like:

```
time      behavior Number
10:04:36  FEED     1
10:04:37  FEED     1
10:04:38  REST     2
10:04:39  REST     2
10:04:40  RUN      3
```

Therefore, if the behaviors at 10:04:36 and 10:30:00 are both FEED, they are still recognized as different behavior events because they have different numbers. I then subsetted my data by behavior category so that I have a dataset of all one behavior. However, in this data set I have Number categories for each time I have a new behavior event, for example:

```
time      behavior Number
10:04:36  FEED     1
10:04:37  FEED     1
10:30:00  FEED     10
10:30:01  FEED     10 
10:30:02  FEED     10
11:01:00  FEED     21
11:01:01  FEED     21
```

etc...

Now, what I would like to do is randomize this new dataset by Number category. So I would like to tell R to take each chunk of data with the same Number value and reorganize these chunks. I tried to use sample(), but that only seems to work for randomizing by row. As you can see the Number categories  are not all the same size either. Basically I would like to create a new matrix that looks something like this:

```
time      behavior Number
10:30:00  FEED     10
10:30:01  FEED     10 
10:30:02  FEED     10    
11:01:00  FEED     21
11:01:01  FEED     21
10:04:36  FEED     1
10:04:37  FEED     1
```

So, I would like R to recognize each new Number category as a distinct event, and randomly reorganize the data by each new event, not by row.

Does anyone know a way to do what I am trying to do in R?

Comment: Can you give a desired output, I'm not sure what you want. For the last block of code, what do you want to do to it? If I take both `Number == 1` rows how do you want them permuted?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but you probably could just create a new column using `sample`, something like `df$NewOrder <- sample(df$Number)` and then reorder your data set by it, i.e., `df <- df[order(df$NewOrder), ]`

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the confusion, I am still trying to figure out the best way to make my point. I made some edits, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a helper funciton, such as

```
reorderingFunc <- function(data, indxCol){
  indx <- sample(unique(data[, indxCol]))
  data[order(unique(data[, indxCol])[match(data[, indxCol], indx)]), ]
}
```

Testing

```
set.seed(111) # Setting a seed so the outcome of `sample` be reproducible
reorderingFunc(df, "Number")
#       time behavior Number
# 3 10:30:00     FEED     10
# 4 10:30:01     FEED     10
# 5 10:30:02     FEED     10
# 6 11:01:00     FEED     21
# 7 11:01:01     FEED     21
# 1 10:04:36     FEED      1
# 2 10:04:37     FEED      1
```

Comment: If you won't use `set.seed` you will give different result each time (`set.seed` was only in order to reproduce your exact desired output).